# Caution while extending a class which is Serializable

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb, xml-binding

I have a class `A` implementing `Serializable` and another class `B extends A`, but I want to use class `B` for XML binding, not for serialization.

Is there anything I should worry about?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've implemented all of the `Serializable` methods in `A`, nope. You won't need to worry about implementing them, since that's already done. If there are any naming conflicts between XML binding and serialization, you can define the method in `B` and your XML binding library will call the methods for `B`, not those of `A` (i.e. [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)).

The only potential worry is a method that takes an argument of type `Serializable` -- if `B`, for whatever reason, shouldn't be (de)serialized, this is a problem. I doubt that this is a problem for you, if only because there are so few cases when it would apply.